# Change every letter of a REALLY long string

Tags: java, encoding, cryptography

I'm trying to make a program that changes every letter to something else
i.e a=q, b=w, c=e and so on...

The program works fine when i insert smaller Strings, but when i try to read a file and input the returned String to my method, it does not translate the letters correctly. My method looks like this:

```
    public static String converString(String conversionString) {

    String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String encodedLetters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";

   conversionString = conversionString.toLowerCase();

    char[] letterChar = letters.toCharArray();
    char[] encChar = encodedLetters.toCharArray();

    char[] stringChar = conversionString.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringChar.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < letterChar.length; j++) {
            if(letterChar[j] == stringChar[i]) {
                conversionString = conversionString.replace(letterChar[j], encChar[j]);
            }
        }

    }
    return conversionString;

}
```

It works fine if i input a small string for it to convert, but when i read a BIG text file(done like this:)

```
public class ReadFile {


public String readFile(Charset encoding) throws IOException {

    {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("HugeTextFile.txt"));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }
```

it doesnt work properly(it works fine if the text file is small, but the text i want to convert is 1k+ lines)

Here's a sample output of some of the text i get, when i try to convert a big file:

```
   qlqqq'l qqqqfqqqql qf qqfqqqlqfq

lqqql qqqqqll

qqqqqqq q. qqqf qqq qqqqqq-qqlq

qlqqq qql qqqqffqfq qq qqq qqqf qqqqq qf lqqqqfq qf qqq lqlqqq qf qqq
qqfq, qfq qf qqqqfq fqqqqfq qq qq: qfqq qq qqqqq lqq qqq qqqqqq qfqq qqq
qqqq qqq lqlqqq qql qqqqqfq, qqq qq qqq fq qqqqqqql qq qqfqqqlqqqqfl qf
qq, 'qfq qqqq ql qqq qlq qf q qqqq,' qqqqqqq qlqqq 'qqqqqqq qqqqqqql qq
qqfqqqlqqqqfl?'

lq lqq qql qqflqqqqqfq qf qqq qqf qqfq (ql qqll ql lqq qqqlq, fqq qqq
```

But the text itself does not use that many a's, as this is outputting. Can anyone help me explain why this is happening with big texts only?

Comment: Why don't you use directly String.replace to change the letters?

Comment: If the file is really huge you may want to stream it rather than reading it all in one go

Comment: The outer cycle is not needed. But the real problem is that sometimes you are replacing already replaced characters, thus making numerous redundant replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are replacing already replaced characters. As far as I understand, you want to change letters in your string according to the "dictionary" you provided. Using data structures you are using, this problem can be solved like this:

```
public static String convertString(String conversionString) {

  String letters =        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  String encodedLetters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";

  conversionString = conversionString.toLowerCase();

  char[] letterChar = letters.toCharArray();
  char[] encChar = encodedLetters.toCharArray();

  char[] stringChar = conversionString.toCharArray();

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < stringChar.length; i++) {
    int j = letters.indexOf(stringChar[i]); 
    sb.append(conversionString.substring(i, i + 1).replace(letterChar[j], encChar[j]));   
  }

  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The outer-loop was indeed the problem :)

Comment: Glad to help, consider studying other answers, for example sandy's, where ASCII table is utilized to find a proper index in your encoded array.

Comment: I tried looking into sandy's answer, and it works great when i implement it, but I don't understand why it works.

I looked into ASCII tables and saw that 97-122 contains all letters from a-z, so i assume it has something to do with that?

Comment: Every lowercase letter in ASCII table has an assigned code, starting with 97. Let's use 97 as a magic number. When you want to convert "aaa" string, you subtract 97 from char 'a' (which can be cast to an int) three times and get a sequence of three zeros. In your encChar array zero index points at 'q'. So you get "qqq", as you wanted. Makes sense? Even more, for now you can just throw out letterChar array as redundant, because you use indices, which are exact values for those ones in ASCII table if you add 97. The whole case possible because you are using alphabetic string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
for(int i=0;i<stringChar.length;i++){
    stringChar[i]=encChar[stringChar[i]-97];
}
```

Comment: This is very nice.

Comment: I tried this and it works great, but I'm having a hard time understanding why it's working. Where's the -97 coming from?

Comment: 97 is the ASCII code for 'a'. Subtracting from ith character, gives you index in range 0 to 25. For ex. 'c' - 97 = 99 - 97 = 2. And encChar[2] will give you its encoded character.